# NoraUI - "Cannot infer Type argument" error using Result.Warning<> in a custom step

Tags: java, noraui

I need to raise a warning during one of my scenario but i don't stop to have this error appearing : "Cannot infer type arguments for Result.Warning<>"

I actually tried to raise the Warning the same way i was raising Failure until now :

```
new Result.Warning<>(targetKey, Messages.format(TaroMessages.WARNING_RESOURCES_VALUE_DIFFERENCE_AFTER_REAFFECTATION, existing_value, new_value), true, oscarAccesClientPage.getCallBack());
```

The custom step i am using it inside is the following : I'm trying to go over a list of Element and checking that the existing value of them is the same or not as the one saved before.

```
protected void checkXyResourcesValue(Integer xyIterator, List<WebElement> elements, String keyParameter) throws TechnicalException, FailureException  {
        try {
            Integer resIterator = 1;
            for(WebElement element : elements) {
                String targetKey = "XY" + xyIterator + "RES" + resIterator + keyParameter;
                String new_value = element.getAttribute(VALUE) != null ? element.getAttribute(VALUE) : element.getText();
                String existing_value = Context.getValue(targetKey) != null ? Context.getValue(targetKey) : targetKey;
                if (new_value != existing_value) {
                    new Result.Warning<>(targetKey, Messages.format(TaroMessages.WARNING_RESOURCES_VALUE_DIFFERENCE_AFTER_REAFFECTATION, existing_value, new_value), true, oscarAccesClientPage.getCallBack());
                }
                resIterator++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            new Result.Failure<>(e.getMessage(), Messages.format(TaroMessages.FAIL_MESSAGE_ACCES_CLIENT_XY_CHECK_RESOURCES_VALUE, keyParameter, xyIterator), true, oscarAccesClientPage.getCallBack());
        }
    }
```

For the method to check and saved value I actually inspired myself for the piece of code from NoraUI to save a value on Context or read it from.

I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 and i try to compile using JDK1.8.0_131.

It may be more related to me not knowing how this work in Java than a real problem so thank you in advance for your help or insights. Don't hesitate to ask if you need more information on the piece of code or the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new Result.Warning<>(targetKey, Messages.format(TaroMessages.WARNING_RESOURCES_VALUE_DIFFERENCE_AFTER_REAFFECTATION, existing_value, new_value), true, **0**);

use 0 if you do not use any Model (data serialized) or use id of your Object in the serial.

Comment: It works fine, thanks you ! I did not go far enough in the API to see the last argument was of a different type.

Another question i have (which might need a new question on overflow I don't know) : The Warning cause no error and the code can run. But i can't see the warning anywhere in the log or the HTML report. If i can't see them here, where am i supposed to see them ?

Comment: You can see a message "Alerte: ....." in HTML repport + a screenshot. In Excel data output, you have a orange color message.